# Linode: can you have multiple instances with one linode?

Tags: vps, linode

I havent had extensive use of vps before. I was wondering, if I purchase one node from Linode, can I run deploy multiple instances? Similar to Amazon EC2? Or would I have to purchase another Linode separately?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you will—you're paying for guaranteed resources in a particular location, so another Linode it is.

Comment: ok, but can I "breakdown" a linode to multiple instances?

Comment: @Newton: no—there's no difference between a "Linode" and an "instance" (unless you further define what an "instance" means, because I'm not sure we're using the same terms). Pretend a Linode is a real computer in a datacentre somewhere; it can't be broken up.

Comment: Im guessing then I can set up my own virtual private servers inside this "datacentre"?

Comment: @Newton: yes; those are each Linodes.

Comment: ok, sorry, i should have rephrased - can i set up my own virtual private servers inside the linode? if yes, is that a common practice? i.e. buy a large linode and have couple of vps inside it?

Comment: @Newton: I don't know of any way to do so—as far as I'm aware, you can't nest a Xen hypervisor within another one. That said, I'm more interested to hear *why* you would want to do so. It would surely be more efficient/economical to just buy multiple Linodes from the outset?

Comment: true, I was trying to figure out whether it would make sense to buy a bigger node and split it up, than buying multiple Linodes - and whether to go for a Linode instance or EC2 instance

Comment: It really depends on what you're trying to achieve, exactly—I'm not familiar with the actual problem you want to solve, so I can't be any more useful, unfortunately!

Answer (score 0):

I understand what you trying to say, under single VPS linode instance multiple deployment not possible as of now.